# Show that $\mathbb{E}[X_t]=X_0e^{-ct}$ if $X_t=X_0e^{-ct}+\sigma e^{-ct}\int_0^te^{cs}dW_s$, $X_0\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

so I know the result is trivially correct, but I am being asked to prove it. I tried using a theorem, but it seems rather contradictory. Thanks in advance!

**Question:** Show that $\mathbb{E}[X_t]=X_0e^{-ct}$ if $X_t=X_0e^{-ct}+\sigma e^{-ct}\int_0^te^{cs}dW_s$, $X_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c,\sigma>0$

**Attempt:**

Let $M_t=e^{cs} dWs$, then if $\mathbb{E}\int_0^t(M_t)^2<\infty$ for all $t\ge 0$, we will have that $\{M_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ is a martingale, so $\mathbb{E}(M_t)=\mathbb{E}(M_0)=0$.

However, I get
$$\mathbb{E}\int_0^te^{2cs}ds=\left[\frac{e^{2cs}}{2c}\right]_0^t=\frac{e^{2ct}-1}{2c}$$
However, as far as I know that goes to $\infty$ as $t\to \infty$.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: Is there supposed to be an integral in your definition of $M_t$?

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake there. $M_t=e^{cs}$? The result would still be the same, but I guess that would make more sense.

Comment: Well, you can define $M_t$ however you want. But if you want it to be a martingale it should probably be a stochastic integral, not $M_t=e^{cs} dWs$.

Answer (score 2):

If $M = \int h dX$ where $X$ is a continuous square integrable martingale, you don't need $E\int_0^\infty h_s^2d\langle X\rangle_s < \infty$ for $M$ to be a martingale, you just need $E\int_0^t h_s^2d\langle X\rangle_s < \infty$ for all $t$. You did show this, and hence your $M$ is a martingale and you can say $E M_t = E M_0$ to solve your problem.

Comment: OK, thanks! So I guess that I don't have to consider the case when $t\to\infty$ in this proof, just if there are any non-finite values such as in the case of $1/t$, which goes to $\infty$ when $t=0$?

Comment: You are correct that $\int 1/t dX$ would be a problem, but it may be a bigger problem than you realize! Because $E\int_0^t \frac{1}{s} d\langle X \rangle_s = \infty$ for all $t$ for most of the $X$'s that you will encounter, e.g. Brownian motion. Remember that we only define the stochastic integral if $P \left(\int_0^t h(s)d\langle X \rangle_s < \infty\right) = 1$ for all $t\geq 0$. And in this case we only know that $\int h dX$ is a local martingale. So in the case of $\int 1/t dB_t$, we can't even define the stochastic integral, let alone ensure that it is a martingale.

Answer (score 1):

To add onto nullUser's response. Of course $\int_0^t 1 dW_s=W_t$ is a martingale right? Well:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} 1 ds=\infty$$

This is just to give a solid counterexample, the rest was explained in his post.